# How to get request headers of every page traversed during replay in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, servlets

**Problem Statement:** Unable to get the headers of each page traversed during script replay in Selenium - Java.

Selenium 3.141

I'm not pretty sure on how to get the request headers(as shown in expected result) for every page we visit during script replay in Selenium. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
URL obj = new URL("https://3d.login");
URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
System.out.println(conn.getHeaderFields());
```

Returns an empty output

**Expected Result:**

Request URL: https://3d.login/emxTree.jsp?objectId=33423.10679.48703.58250&mode=insert

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 200

Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8888

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Actual Result:**
Empty

Answer (score 0):

May be u can use something like this.

```
String s = new HttpRequest(GET, driver.getCurrentUrl()).getHeaderNames();
```

Comment: Thanks @Neerajkumar but I still get an empty output.